# How to get the permalink of a page when loading my plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, permalinks

I'm implementing a web widget and for this reason I'd like my script to respond to the request as soon as possible, to avoid loading unnecessary thing.
I've found out that calling `get_permalink( $page_id )` before the `init` phase return this error:

> **[19-Sep-2012 12:10:12 UTC] PHP Fatal error**: Call to a member function `get_page_permastruct()` on a non-object in `...\wp-includes\link-template.php` on *line 276*

I was wondering is there a way in which i can retrieve the permalink of the page without waiting for the `init` phase?

Answer (score 1):

`setup_theme` is the earliest action you can call `get_permalink()` on. the [rewrite class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite) gets instantiated after `plugins_loaded` and before `setup_theme` in `wp-settings.php`, which is the object the error refers to. `get_page_permastruct()` is a method of the rewrite class.

Answer (score 0):

The error message means that `$page_id` is not set. Try using `get_query_var('p')` instead?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're wrong. It clearly says that it wants to call `get_page_permastruct()` method on `$wp_rewrite` object, but this object isn't initialized so its undefined and this call ends with fatal error. If you were right, it would be notice/warning not fatal error.